# Xcode custom fonts show up in Attributes Inspector, but only Regular is selectable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, custom-font

I added a custom font to Xcode. And in the Attributes Inspector, FontFamilly is visible, but only Regular can be selected.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

[Adding files inside the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFcCB.png)

[Add font files to info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERUBj.png)

[Check Target Membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtKfA.png)

[After selecting Font as Custom in the Attributes Inspector, the added font family is confirmed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKiCe.png)

[However, Bold or Extra Bold are not shown in Style, only Regular is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgqkS.png)

Comment: Have you registered your fonts in plist.?

Xcode creates an array value for the key; add the name of the font file as an item of the array. Be sure to include the file extension as part of the name.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app